# AngularJS UI Router query parameters search not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, search

I have a very simple search app using UI Router with 2 states, 2 templates and 1 controller. I have home(enter search query) and search(display results, search more) - states and templates - and am attempting to get the query parameters in the url from home state to search state WITH search results displaying on the first query submission.

What is currently happening is you enter the search query on the home state and you go to the search state and the query parameters appear in the BUT it takes a second search submission for the results to display.

I believe I'm using $stateParams correctly it seems, however I think I'm either missing something or don't have my states setup correctly for this scenario to work as intended.

Do I need to use [$location](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1143) and if so, how? Should I have home as a parent state and then have search as a child state of home and use `abstract:true` ? Should I not use `html5Mode`? Trying to get my head around UI Router, not so easy... It seems like this should be easier than what I'm making it to be?

Here are my states

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
        url: '/home',           
        templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'})         
      .state('search', {            
        templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
        url: '/search?q',           
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      });    
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

This is how I'm using `$stateParams` in SearchCtrl

```
$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.q;
```

searchTerms is my ng-model on the search form

And this is how I'm using `$state.go()` in my search function in SearchCtrl

```
$state.go('search', {q: $scope.searchTerms});
```

Comment: Just updated one of my fiddles to include your requirement. Check this out https://plnkr.co/edit/Huoe0ypNMEhxhZwIUaVO?p=preview

Comment: @Developer got pulled away on diff project give me a while to check it out

Comment: No problem. Let me know if that fiddle works for you, I'll put description as answer tomorrow. In case if that's not the scenario you are looking for, try to create a plunkr so that I could check what's wrong in your case.